# Ad-hoc based chat application on Qt (without a router)

Tags: qt, networking, adhoc

I am writing a chat application in QML/C++. I have already implemented an option to chat locally (with people in the same network) and I am currently working in implementing a bluetooth chat option.

However, one early user of my application suggested me to implement an ad-hoc based chat option that would communicate each device directly (without the need of a router, in other words, peer-to-peer). This feature would be very useful if the user(s) are located in a  place without an internet access point, say a music festival or in an event.

My application uses the Qt framework and it has the necessary tools for me to implement this feature, however, I am a hobbyist programmer and I don't have a lot experience dealing with network connections.

Do you know any way to implement this ad-hoc, peer-to-peer feature? (or know any helpful websites/links).

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Comment: Take a look at [Wi-Fi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct). Both [Windows 8 and newer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439487.aspx) and [Android ICS and newer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html) support this type of networking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TCP or UDP protocol for your chat application. 
TCP = connected protocol
UDP = "broadcast" protocol, more speed

Example here : 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/network-chat.html

Or here : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/examples-network.html

Yekmen

Comment: This will work only if there will be simple network architecture -> each user must have an unique IP + broadcasting should be enabled + no NAT should be used (or routing should be configurated, what is not possible according to original question)